# Scrollmagic setPin Method Causes Link issues in Create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, animation, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm using Scrollmagic and GSAP in my create-react-app and pinning a section while child elements are animated on scroll. I've achieved this HOWEVER anytime I click on my nav links (using [Reach Router](https://github.com/reach/router)) it goes to an empty/white page.

When inspecting elements in Chrome, the `<div id="root"></div>` is not fed any data which explains the empty/white page. If I refresh that page, it renders all content as expected. Additionally, it will also render if I comment out `.setPin('#scrollStarts')` line.

The empty/white page also throws the following errors:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

Has anyone experiencing similar behavior and able to find solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a parent/wrapping `<div>` and it solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!